# lambda function to convert dict to string as a lambda expression in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How to convert a dict to string in python using a lambda expression?

something like this which is for list to strings

```
list_to_str = lambda x: ','.join(x) if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) else x
```

Note: No specific output, just a generic lambda expression

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: The join built in function doesn't coverts list or tuple to string. It joins all the elements based on the sperator we provide i.e ',' in your case.

Comment: how is this different to `repr`? Saying "No specific output" is just wasting everyone's time. Give at least one example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your use case is, see if this suits you:

```
dict_to_str = lambda x: ','.join("%s:%s" % (str(k), str(v)) for (k, v) in x.iteritems()) if isinstance(x, dict) else x
```